# Inductive proof for increasing function.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I'm working on the following exercise:

> If $f_n : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a function we take $f^k(x)$ to denote the $k$-fold
>   iteration $f(f(\ldots f(x)))$ of $f$ applied to $x$. In the special case $k = 0$,
>   we take $f^0(x)$ to denote $x$.
>
> Now define the sequence of functions $f_n : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ as follows:
>
> $f_0(0) = 1$;
>
> $f_0(1) = 2$;
>
> $f_0(x) = x + 2$ for $x > 1$;
>
> $f_{n+1}(x) = f^k(x)$
>
> Give an inductive proof that, for all $n$, $f_n$ is increasing: $x < y \implies f_n(x) < f_n(y)$.

What I've done:

I've done the base case:

I need to prove that $f_0(x) < f_0(y)$. If $x = 0$, $y = 1$ then $f_0(x) = 1$ and $f_0(y) = 2$, so $f_0(x) < f_0(y)$ so base case is OK.

But I don't really know what I need to do for the inductive step. I know I have to prove that $f_{n+1}(x) < f_{n+1}(y)$ but I'm not sure how to do that. Any steps/hints in the right direction would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In defining the sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, you have mentioned that $f_{n+1}=f^k(x)$. What is $k$? Do you meant $f_{n+1}(x)=f^n(x)$? If so, since $f^n(x)=f(f(\cdots f(x)))$ what is $f(x)$? Probably you meant $f_{n+1}(x)=f_n^n(x)$?

Comment: You haven't proven the base case fully yet. You have shown that $f_0(x)<f_0(y)$ only when $x=0,y=1$. But you need to show that $f_0(x)<f_0(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x<y$.